# 3D-plot values at specific coords

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have a `6000*3` matrix `Points` of 6000 (x,y,z) points representing a surface in space.
I also have a `6000*3` matrix `fieldValues` such that each row in `Points` is the location of the field value in the same row in `fieldValues`:

```
Points(1,:) = -0.0198   -0.0889   -0.0561

fieldValues(1,:) = 0.7184   -0.1626   -0.0184
```

so in `(-0.0198   -0.0889   -0.0561)` which is a point in space, I have a field which its x part is 0.7184, y part is -0.1626   and z part is -0.0184.

How can I plot `fieldValues` as a function of Points so I can observe how the field acts according to where it is.

Thanks

Comment: you mean something like a correlation plot ?

Comment: Something like surf function. I give it the Points matrix and the fieldValues matrix as the color matrix so in that way i get a color representation for each value. I tried that but i get an error "Error using surf (line 69)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector." Not quite sure why he refers to Z as the color matrix.

Comment: so use: `surf(Points(:,1),Points(:,2),Points(:,3),FieldValues)` ?

Comment: That's what I did and got the error above

Comment: so for each `x,y,z` you have `v1,v2,v3`. Thats 6 dimensional space, and you can not plot it.